# Problem with webpack while runnig React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I trying to run React project but getting following error. I tried reinstall `node_modules`, changed node version but without success.

[image]

Comment: I already resolved a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure Webpack version, but I can see webpack is saying **applyWebpackOptionsPlugins** is not a valid property. If you will remove it, error will be vanish.